# Unable to set Global Options in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using following code to set global options in Chart.js

```
Chart.defaults.global = {
    animationSteps: 30,
    tooltipCornerRadius: 0
}

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    var LChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
});
```

It however gives me error

```
TypeError: fn is not a function
```

on line 499 in Chart.js

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please provide us the full codes or at least the related codes to this error.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of doing this

```
Chart.defaults.global = {
    animationSteps: 30,
    tooltipCornerRadius: 0
}
```

you should do this

```
Chart.defaults.global.animationSteps = 30;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipCornerRadius = 0;
```

When you do the former, you are wiping out all the default values by putting in an entirely new global object (instead of just changing the properties you want to). The only way to get *that* to work would be define each and every property.

Comment: OMG, that was so obvious! I struggled for 2 hours wondering why the defaults are not set while I was wiping them myself. Pure genius!